# Why is ngModel not correctly updating my variable when it is sent as a $resource in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs

Here's how I defined my $resource:

```
app.factory('User', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/user', {}, {
        get: { method:'GET'},
        update: { method:'PUT'},
    })
})
```

And here's my controller:

```
function SettingsCtrl($scope, $http, User) {
    $scope.user = User.get(
        {}, //Params

        function(data) { //Successfully received data

        },
        function(data) { //Failure to receive data

        }
    );

    $scope.saveUser = function() {
        $scope.user.$update();
        console.log($scope.user);
    };
}
```

The `User.get()` call at the top of the controller is correctly getting the data from the backend.  In my HTML I've made a button that calls the `$scope.saveUser` function and created some inputs with `ng-model`, and it would appear that two-way data binding is working correctly.  When I call `console.log($scope.user)` in the `$scope.saveUser` function, it returns the user object exactly as I expected, with the changes I made in my browser.  However, on my Node backend, I log the object as it was received in the PUT request, and it does not reflect any changes I made in my browser, it looks identical to the original.  After I click the button in my browser, the data is reset to its original value.  What is going on?  Why won't it send the updated data that I've typed in my browser?

Comment: Can you post the output from the Node.js console regarding the `PUT` that you receive when `saveUser` is called? I have a few thoughts, but I'm not sure which direction to go. :)

Comment: Sure.  Here is `console.log($scope.user)` from the browser after I edited the form and hit Save (which calls `saveUser`):

`[14:28:56.097] ({__v:0, _id:"50b1a966c12ef0c426000007", password:"NEW MODIFIED PASSWORD"})`

And here's what Node logs as `console.log(req.user)`:  
`{__v:0, _id:"50b1a966c12ef0c426000007", password:"originalPassword"})`

Comment: I mean, that doesn't give you any more info than what was in the question.  Did you want the full PUT request with all the headers and junk?  It's really long.

Comment: I would think that it would either send the new data, or no data at all--I'm working on a half-finished answer, but I think I need to dig into `angular-resource.js` a bit.

Comment: I notice you're logging `req.user`; this threw a yellow flag, and I wanted to make sure that's the right object. It seems that it should be `req.body.user`--in my apps, `req.user` is usually something attached to the `req` object via  middleware, to say what the "current user" is.

Comment: If it *is* the right object, perhaps it would be useful to see the full `PUT` request headers--[http://gist.github.com/](http://gist.github.com/) might be a good place to paste it.

Comment: THANK YOU SIR!  You were correct, `req.user` is the middleware session stuff.  `req.body` ended up being what I was looking for.  I was pulling my hair out.

Comment: Haha, you got yourself an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)! Happy to have helped. :)

Comment: If you would like to post that as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as answered.  Thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help Brandon.  I've got another Angular $resource question and I think you'd probably be able to help.

http://stackoverflow.com/q/13558868/371273

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment:

> Here is `console.log($scope.user)` from the browser after I edited the form and hit Save (which calls `saveUser`):
>
> ```
> {__v:0, _id:"50b1a966c12ef0c426000007", password:"NEW MODIFIED PASSWORD"}
> ```
>
> And here's what Node logs as `console.log(req.user)`:
>
> ```
> {__v:0, _id:"50b1a966c12ef0c426000007", password:"originalPassword"})
> ```

`req.user` is usually an object attached to the request object to specify who the currently logged in user is, and is usually managed by middleware. Since you're doing a `PUT` request, you're looking for data in `req.body`.