# How do I make an AngularJS $resource update after a POST, PUT, or DELETE request?

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular app, I've setup "project" as a `$resource`.  In my controller, I ask the server for the data over a GET request immediately when the page loads.  I can edit the information in my browser using Angular's two-way data binding, and then I can save the data back to the server via a POST request, like this:

(edited/simplified for brevity)

```
function ProjectCtrl($scope, $routeParams, Project) {
    $scope.project = Project.get({id: $routeParams.projectId},
        function(data) { //Successfully received data }, 
        function(data) { //Failed to receive data },
    );

    $scope.saveProject = function() {
        $scope.project.save();
    };
}
```

My Node server correctly receives the data, processes it and makes some changes, saves it to my database, and then responds with the newly updated "project" object via JSON.  Angular does not display the new object until I refresh the page.  Is there any way to make it display the new data?  I'm assuming there's a more automatic Angular way to do this than to manually call another GET request after `$scope.project.save();`

Comment: it may be totally irrelevant, but I think it should be '$scope.project.$save()'.

Comment: If you pass a callback into `save`, what do you get as `arguments` (e.g.: `$scope.project.save(function() { console.log(arguments); });`)? (My hope is that the first argument will be data from the server, but I'm not positive.)

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is.  Here's what it logs:  `({0:{__v:11, _id:"50b18fb934d3488cb888163f", otherData:""}}), 

1:(function (c){
"use strict";
a||(a=Nb(b));return c?a[E(c)]||null:a})})`

So should I set `$scope.project` equal to `arguments[0]` or what would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: I'm not in a good position to check, but see if you can do `$scope.project = Project(data)` (just use `data` as the first parameter to that function).

Comment: Unfortunately, it says `data is undefined`.  I set `$scope.project = arguments[0]` and it works, but I figured there was a more correct way.  I'm not doing anything crazy in the JSON response, but will the object I'm looking for always be at index 0 in `arguments[0]`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like the server response comes back as the first argument to the callback to `save`, so as long as the server responds with the *full* object data, you should be able to use it to create a "new" Project object like this:

```
function ProjectCtrl($scope, $routeParams, Project) {
    $scope.project = Project.get({id: $routeParams.projectId},
        function(data) { /* Successfully received data */ }, 
        function(data) { /* Failed to receive data */ },
    );

    $scope.saveProject = function() {
        $scope.project.save(function(data) {
            $scope.project = new Project(data);
        });
    };
}
```